# How can I limit a KMS key to be used only by a specific cognito user (federated identity ID)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kms

I can't seem to figure the policies needed to make this happen.

I see there's an easy way to connect keys with IAM users but I can't find something like an arn to connect directly to a cognito identity.

I can specify the identity pool but not spesific users.

Am I missing something in the conditions part of the key policy?

Help please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to implement what I want. I'm not sure how secure this is, I might add a condition key from the ones listed here too

Posting here just in case anyone runs into this.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "key-default-1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions for testing",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::<account>:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
            "kms:DeleteKey",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:PutKeyPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Enable cognito User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::<account>:assumed-role/<role name...>-CognitoAuthorizedRole-<...>/CognitoIdentityCredentials"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:GetKeyPolicy",
            "kms:DeleteKey",
            "kms:PutKeyPolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:<region>:<account>:key/<id>",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "<region>:<federated developer identity ID>"
            }
        }
    }
]
```